# Can I redefine an environment to generate an error?

Tags: errors, environments, logging

I know how to use `\renewenvironment` to redefine an environment, but instead of changing formatting, I'd like to have any use of the environment generate an error (log and abort). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `\renewenvironment{tabular}{\ABORT}{}`, assuming of course that the environment `` is already defined (hence the `renew`, otherwise use `new`), and the macro `\ABORT` does not exit or aborts as you desire.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{die}
  {\GenericError{}{Mortal environment found}
  {I'm very unhappy, exiting}
  {What you did is highly disapproved}\endgroup\csname @@end\endcsname}
  {}

\begin{document}
\begin{die}
\end{die}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is as simple as possible:

```
\def\yourenv{\GenericError{}{This is my error}{}{}}
```

Comment: This does not really define the environment (since you did not define `\endyourenv`, btu does generate an error as desired.

Comment: the question is about **re**-defining, so `\endyourenv` should have been already defined before you do this modification.

Comment: Duh!!! Good point. I don't have even a good excuse like too much wine!!