# How to get an error if I use \a or \b in the file

Tags: macros, compiling

I am writing a long paper and I have a few variables I use very frequently. They are labelled `\z`, `\Z`, `\zt`, `\Zt` etc. However I also have a few variables with names 'a' and 'b' in the document which I don't use so frequently. As `\a`, `\b` are already defined macros, I have used `\avar`, `\bvar` as the macros for these. However while typing my file, I frequently forget that I should use `\avar` instead of `\a`. Is there a way for the compiler to give me an error if I use `\a`, `\b` in the document? Thanks!

Comment: Since `\a` and `\b` are defined, that means they are defined to *do* something. If you make them do something else (which is not a good idea in most cases), you might as well make them do what `\avar` does....

Comment: I understand your point. I have no intention of modifying the definition of \a, \b at any point. But is there a way to restrict the use of a macro in some part of the document? The only reason why want to do this is for ease of writing the paper. Whenever I mistakenly write \a, I will get an error and then I change it to \avar and everybody is happy

Comment: Well, I guess one idea would be to prefix or append an undefined command. E.g., `\usepackage{etoolbox} \preto\b{\barf}` (where `\barf` is undefined).

Comment: there is no point in doing this at all!  if you decide that it is safe to redefine `\a` to make an error you may as well have redefined it to make your variable formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to what is mentioned in [Can I redefine an environment to generate an error?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48301/5764), you can add the following to your preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand{\a}{\GenericError{}{Don't use \string\a!}{}{}}
  \renewcommand{\b}{\GenericError{}{Don't use \string\b!}{}{}}
}

\begin{document}

This is a test. \a{} and \b.

\end{document}
```